# How to create shapefiles with z coordinate with QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, z-value

I'm working with QGIS, and I want to create a shapefile with the elevation coordinate, I can't find something similar to what I was used to do in ArcGIS, can you help me?

Comment: I you are digitizing either points or polygons you can define a field in the attribute table to store your elevations. It would be helpful to know what you were use to do in ArcMap

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding QGIS 2.0 does not have that ability. Other may know better, but I heard it will be available in future releases. An option would be to use PostGIS 2.0, which has 3D geometry as an option.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45197/what-is-xyz-format-in-qgis  see this from before.

Comment: you can use other Python modules in the Python console, look at [How to create a 3D shapefile from a raster?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57091/how-to-create-a-3d-shapefile-from-a-raster)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the

> v.to.3d

GRASS GIS 7 tool from the Processing Toolbox. In this tool you can select your input vector map (shapefile) and define the attribute column which holds the elevations. After the processing your features have real z values.

[image: v.to.3d]